# Loop into function R

Tags: r

is there any way of transforming a for loop into a function in R?

For example if I have

```
test <- array(0, dim = c(12))
for (i in 1:12 ){
   test[i] <- test[i] * X * Y
}
```

setting outside the loop the value of X and Y.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
testFunc <- function(x, X, Y){
  x * X * Y
}
test <- sapply(test, testFunc, X, Y)
```